# Why is the digamma function written as ψ rather than ϝ or Ϝ?

Tags: notation, math-history, digamma-function

The gamma function is written with the upper-case letter Γ, but the digamma function is usually written with the lower-case letter ψ. How did this notation come about? Why is it ψ rather than the lower-case digamma glyph ϝ, or better still the upper-case digamma Ϝ?

I can imagine that the upper-case digamma Ϝ was avoided due to its similarity with the Latin F. But even that seems like a weak excuse when χ, ρ, and ν show up pretty frequently, not to mention the potential for confusion between x and ×.

Comment: Maybe the first person who studied the digamma function didn't know the glyph digamma, like me... hahaha

Comment: True, but at least someone had to know enough to *name* it "digamma", unless they thought they were just being clever with Greek and the whole thing is a coincidence. But that seems too coincidental to be plausible, especially since $Ϝ$ has a similar shape to $\frac{Γ'}{Γ}$

Comment: The [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a more-appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Presumably because the [lowercase digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma) was not present in the "standard" keybords with greek symbols used to type mathematical texts.

Comment: @shadowtalker Yeah. I was joking a little. The question is very interesting in my opinion. I could expect to name $\Gamma'/\Gamma$ as $\gamma$. But then the name "digamma" is strange. Anyway... we will see the answers

Comment: @Blue it looks like there's already an answer there! https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6790/4170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of marking this as "answered", this question was addressed on the History of Mathematics forum: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6862/4170

> this function was used, and denoted “psi”, much before it got a name.